# Error with pygmentize when using minted package

Tags: minted, paths, python, pygments, macports

**Problem:**

I get multiple undefined control sequences when using the package `minted` and I believe it is caused by pygmentize.

**Background**

I use the software `Texpad` and the active LaTeX distribution is set to:

- `/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-darwin`

I then check both `python` and `pygmentize`:

- `which python` results in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`
- `which pygmentize` results in `/opt/local/bin/pygmentize`

I have MacPorts installed and I check the active version by using:

- `port select --list python` which results in `python34 (active)`

**Question 1**

This is where I get confused, shouldn't `which python` also point to `/opt/local/bin/python`?

**Paths**

I check my `paths` by doing `nano ~/.bash_profile`, which results in:

```
export PATH=/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-darwin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/:$PATH

##
# Your previous /Users/Batman/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/Batman/.bash_profile.macports-saved_$
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2017-02-12_at_00:07:31: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
```

**Question 2**

What is required given the above information in order for pygmentize to work?

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{minted}

\usemintedstyle[php]{autumn}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{php}
<?php
    try {
        // Connect to SQL database
        $dsn = new PDO('mysql:host=servername;dbname=databasename', 'username', 'password');
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        // Prints out error message
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

So after some searching I found the answer here:

https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/81#issuecomment-125685237

and the solution was:

```
\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}
```

If the errors continue one might try:

```
\usepackage[cache=false,outputdir=.texpadtmp]{minted}
```

The issue seems to be with the `minted` package and not associated with `pygmentize`.

Answer (score -1):

The pygmentize issue can be addressed by installing pygments with pip2.

```
sudo pip2 install pygments
```

This method works on my cases.