# Listings : avoid white line glitches in background color?

Tags: color, listings, backgrounds

With the following code I get some glitches in the background color of my listing environment:

[image]

How can I avoid these glitches? Aside from this issue, the margin top and bottom is different. The code box should be centered between the two paragraphs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lstfiracode}

\setCJKmainfont{ipaexm.ttf}
\setmonofont{Fira Code}

\lstset{
  language=C,
  style=FiraCodeStyle,
  basicstyle=\setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}\ttfamily\footnotesize,
  commentstyle=\rmfamily\itshape\color{gray},
  backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
  frame=single,
  framerule=0pt,
  framextopmargin=3ex,
  framexbottommargin=3ex,
  framexleftmargin=1em,
  xleftmargin={\dimexpr 1em+3pt},
  linewidth={\dimexpr \linewidth-3pt}
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{lstlisting}
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    printf("hello, world!\n");
}
\end{lstlisting}
\lipsum[2][1-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: use tcolorbox to create listings with colored backgrounds. It works much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Major Edit

I have rewritten the entire example using `tcolorbox` and `minted`. I'll leave the old solution here, since it works ok and comes closer to the original requirements.

### If pygments is neither installed nor in the path

Update your TeX-Distribution. Until the installation and/or path issues aren't resolved, this can be used:

```
latexmk -lualatex -shell-escape foo.tex
```

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{blindtext}
% \usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lstfiracode}
\usepackage[
    listings
    % minted
]{tcolorbox}
% \usepackage{minted}

% \setCJKmainfont{ipaexm.ttf}
% \setmonofont{Fira Code}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[1]

\begin{tcblisting}{
    % listing engine=minted,
    % minted style=trac,
    % minted language=c,
    listing only,
    boxrule=1pt,
}
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    printf("hello, world!\n");
}
\end{tcblisting}

\blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

### The new version

This offers beautiful syntax highlighting and leaves almost nothing to the imagination:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% \usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lstfiracode}
\usepackage[most,minted]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{minted}

% \setCJKmainfont{ipaexm.ttf}
% \setmonofont{Fira Code}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-3]

\begin{tcblisting}{
    listing engine=minted,
    minted style=trac,
    minted language=c,
    listing only,
    boxrule=1pt,
}
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    printf("hello, world!\n");
}
\end{tcblisting}

\lipsum[2][1-3]
\end{document}
```

The output is really nice and highly customizable:

[image: New Listing with tcolorbox and minted]

### The old version

Well, there have been many solutions for your problem:

- [Unwanted White Lines in listings environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129377/unwanted-white-lines-in-listings-environment)
- [Listings lstlisting environment has white horizontal lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334100/listings-lstlisting-environment-has-white-horizontal-lines)

and even here:

- [Stripes in background color drawn by listings package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374151/stripes-in-background-color-drawn-by-listings-package)

Yet, there always seemed to be a catch. This here seems to work quite reliably:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
% \usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lstfiracode}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

% \setCJKmainfont{ipaexm.ttf}
% \setmonofont{Fira Code}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.75}

\lstset{
  language=C,
  style=FiraCodeStyle,
  basicstyle=\setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}\ttfamily\footnotesize,
  commentstyle=\rmfamily\itshape\color{gray},
%   frame=single,
%   framerule=0pt,
%   framextopmargin=3ex,
%   framexbottommargin=3ex,
%   framexleftmargin=1em,
%   xleftmargin={\dimexpr 1em+3pt},
%   linewidth={\dimexpr \linewidth-3pt},
  aboveskip=1.5em,
  belowskip=1em,
}

\surroundwithmdframed[
  hidealllines=true,
  backgroundcolor=light-gray,
  innerleftmargin=15pt,
  innertopmargin=0pt,
  innerbottommargin=0pt]{lstlisting}

\mdfsetup{skipabove=1.5em,skipbelow=1em}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-3]

\begin{lstlisting}
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    printf("hello, world!\n");
}
\end{lstlisting}

\lipsum[2][1-3]
\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't use mdframed, it is old, in part buggy and unmaintained for quite some time now. tcolorbox is much better.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thank you for being so helpful. In the last couple of days I've learned more than in the last two years! I have rewritten the entire *mwe* and will edit right away.

Comment: With your first solution I have an issue when using `latexmk -xelatex foo.tex`. `Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag.`. Why should I use the shell-escape and how should I use it?

Comment: @phil-elkabat with `-shell-escape` I now have this error `Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output;`

Comment: Is your TeX-Distribution up to date? What OS are you on?

Comment: This might also be helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426667/220875

Comment: @phil-elkabat yes it is up to date and I created an issue there: https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/277

Comment: @nowox, that's great news in a way! I really was beginning to question my problem solving skills. I have edited the answer to include an example without minted. This should compile even without python2.x present. Would you test it and get back to me so I can improve my answer if need be?

Comment: @phil-elkabat Your answer is awesome, nothing to add or change!